# boost 1.41 serialization unsupported version

Tags: serialization, boost

I am reading in a serialized class from memory using Boost 1.41 and am getting an "unsupported version" exception even though the program that produced the serialized class also used Boost 1.41.

I'm using the following method to read the data:

```
void ConvertMessage (const unsigned char *msgAddress)
{
    MessageData messageData;

    int msgSize = msgSystem.getDataSize (message); // external system returns message size
    char *msgData = new char[msgSize];
    memcpy (msgData, msgAddress, msgSize);

    try
    {
        typedef boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> Device;
        boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<Device> msgStream (msgData, msgSize);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive msg (msgStream); // exception thrown here

        msg >> messageData;
    }
    catch (boost::archive::archive_exception const &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    // Code to convert messageData to an internal class.
}
```

I've read that there was an issue with reading archives from pre-Boost 1.44 with Boost 1.44 but I'm seeing the issue with both sides using Boost 1.41.

I was able to run this without an issue when the two programs were using the same libraries as we were on the same computer but now we are on separate computers.

Is there some way to verify that we are actually using the exact same versions?

I'm assuming that if the producer of the serialization is using Boost 1.41 and I'm using Boost 1.41 to deserialize the data there shouldn't be an issue, but I'm seeing the "unsupported version" exception when I try to create the boost::archive::binary_iarchive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the program that was building the stream in memory was using Boost 1.54 so that would explain the reason for the "unsupported version" exception.

I'm now linking to the same library and it is working fine.